# How to compile methods from 2 .ts file?

Tags: javascript, typescript

My goal is to compile methods from 2 .ts file.

My expected result: switchLights.js can access methods from accessRights.js

My actual result: switchLight.js can't find the userIsAdmin method.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p>Lights: <span id="lightsCondition">OFF</span></p>
    <button type="button" onclick="switchLights({role: 'admin'})">Lights <span id="lightsButton">ON</span></button>
    <script src="build/accessRights.js"></script>
    <script src="build/switchLights.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

accessRights.ts

```
export interface User {
  role: string;
}

export function userIsAdmin(user: User): boolean {
  return user.role === "admin";
}
```

switchLights.ts

```
import {User, userIsAdmin} from "./accessRights";

let lightsCondition: boolean = false;

function switchLightsRender() {
  let refLightsCondition = document.getElementById("lightsCondition");
  let refLightsButton = document.getElementById("lightsButton");
  if (refLightsCondition !== null) refLightsCondition.innerHTML = lightsCondition ? "ON" : "OFF";
  if (refLightsButton !== null) refLightsButton.innerHTML = !lightsCondition ? "ON" : "OFF";
}

export function switchLights(user: User) {
  if (!userIsAdmin(user)) return false;
  lightsCondition = !lightsCondition;
  switchLightsRender();
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Are you asking for [JavaScript modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules)? You need `<script type="module" src="build/accessRights.js"></script>` and `<script type="module" src="build/switchLights.js"></script>`

Comment: @jabaa i tried to add `type="module"`. However, now I can this error `index.html:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: switchLights is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:5)`

Comment: This looks like the original problem is solved and you have another problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to load the scripts as [ES6 modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules):

```
<script type="module" src="build/accessRights.js"></script>
```

and

```
<script type="module" src="build/switchLights.js"></script>
```